# Is there a way to initialize an anonymous object using implicits without repeating "this."?

Tags: scala

For example, I have an implicit class enhancing a JavaFX Label class. In short:

```
class EnhanceLabel(val l: Label) extends AnyVal {
    def opacity = l.getOpacity
    def opacity_= (d: Double) { l.setOpacity(s) }
}

object EnhanceLabel {
  implicit def enhanceLabel(x: Label) = new EnhanceLabel(x)
}
```

I'm trying to use it like this (after importing the implicit def enhanceLabel):

```
val l = new Label() {
    opacity = 0.5
}
```

This doesn't compile. Error message is:

```
not found: value opacity
    opacity = 0.5
    ^
```

I have to do:

```
val l = new Label() {
    this.opacity = 0.5
}
```

I assume this is because the opacity setter is from an implicit conversion? Does it need the "this" to do the search for an implicit conversion? Doesn't it assume the "this" if it's missing? If I scale this up a lot, I end up with countless "this." keywords which seems redundant to me. Of course I can shorten it to "x." or something like that but I'd like to get rid of it altogether.

Any hints appreciated.

Curtis

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just make `EnhanceLabel` extend `Label` and then make `l` an anonymous instance of that?

Comment: The first example should compile, you just assigning a value to the field in superclass, no implicit conversion in this case needed

Comment: Another observation is that error messages are helpful! Both for you and for us. Don't just say "this doesn't compile" in your question; tell us how it fails. Forcing yourself to look at that would have revealed to you what @AlexIv said, about `text` being a field that already existed. The compiler knows everything about what you actually wrote (not what you think you wrote) and is the ultimate arbiter. Listen to what it has to say :)

Comment: @Myserious/@Alexlv, I'd like this to work without sub-classing so I could use it with final classes from third-party jars.

Comment: Compiler says: not found: value text
    text = "Hey"
    ^

Comment: @countfloyd compiles and runs fine without any `this` reference. Maybe you r importing the wrong Label?

Comment: @countfloyd i guess you r using pure javafx lib, check out scalafx wrapper project this will solve all your problems

Comment: @Alexlv, what's your secret? I can't get it to work. Using 2.10.2. ScalaFX doesn't work with javafx 8

Comment: Let's not get hung up on the javafx thing. It was just an example. My question is more about coming up with a convenient and succinct way to create and initialize objects using implicitly defined vals or defs. It seems to me that it's pretty much built-in if I didn't have to type "this." everywhere.

Comment: @countfloyd Sorry if i'm wrong, but i think that you not quite good understand what implicits are. There is only impl. conversion and impl. params. You can use them during the object instantiation

Comment: @Alexlv no problem. I think I understand them but I'm not explaining it well. Scala 2.10 added implicit classes which I'm using in place of implicit conversion in this case. During object instantiation, the compiler doesn't seem to search for implicits unless I put the 'this' on it.

Comment: Just to elaborate. It will work and compile if calling methods on the Label class itself (or sub-classes). What doesn't work is calling methods that don't exist in Label or its sub-classes but are obtained from an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

According to the given code you are not calling `text` from `EnhanceLabel` class, but trying to assign value to the `text` field of the [Labeled](https://code.google.com/p/scalafx/source/browse/src/scalafx/scene/control/Labeled.scala?r=563a163645f9b006fd146158b14f7b6d7b9b25e7) class. Also your implicit conversion is not used here cause there is a `text` field in the **Labeled** class, no exception is raised. Scala tries implicit conversion as a last chance to compile your program.

Scala will `EnhanceLabel` in the following case:

```
implicit class EnhanceLabel(val l: Label) {
  var enhanced = _
}

val l = new Label("Text")
l.enhanced = "Other text"
```

Comment: text is perhaps a bad example since Labeled has a private field called text. The point is that this doesn't work for any field or method defined in an implicit class. The compiler error says "not found: value text". I really don't think it's trying to assign to a private field. The point of my question is how to set up the anonymous initializer block without having "this." all over the place.